# GODOX AD200 not firing from Panasonic GX7

Tags: godox

I have a Godox AD200 and an XPro(O) trigger and trying to use it with a GX7. The flash is not firing when I take a photo. If I use the test button on the trigger the flash fires. I think the trigger is seated correctly as it seems to be in as far as it can go but it does stick out a bit from the back. Is there a setting I need in the camera? The same flash works fine from Fuji and Sony cameras with their XPro triggers. The GX7 seems to recognise there is a flash connected as the red flash signal shows when a photo is taken. I using the mechanical shutter. Any idea what the issue is?

Edit: I can get the flash to fire from the camera when hitting the shutter release only if I enable HSS but then it fires before the photo is actually taken so it seems not to be synced.

Comment: What shutter speeds are you trying to use? Are they shorter (faster) than your camera's sync speed?